# How to add double quotes to every line and then add a comma at the end of the line?

Tags: text-processing

The commands to ad double quotes:

```
sed -e 's/.*/\"&\"/' some_file
```

The command to add comma at the end of each line:

```
perl -i -pe 's/$/,/' some_file
```

I've tried both of them,if I add first double quotes and then append comma, only comma is shown.

Suppose if I have a textfile like:

```
aav
afv 
adad
```

I want like:

```
"aav",
"afv",
"adad",
```

Comment: looks like you forgot the `-i` option for `sed`

Comment: Also... `sed -ie 's/^/"/;s/$/",/' some_file`

Comment: Why do you do it in 2 steps? `'s/.*/\"&\",/'` should also work I  guess.

Comment: @Marco, one advantage of muru's version is that it also works for lines that contain bytes not forming valid characters in the current locale (like the output of `printf 'foo\200bar\n'` in a UTF-8 locale).

Answer (score 11):

with `awk`

```
awk '{ printf "\"%s\",\n", $0 }' file
```

Comment: what about single quotes? If I exchange `\"` with `'` or `\'` it doesn't work

Comment: Best is to use hexcodes: `'{printf "\x27\n"}'` where `\x27` represents single quotes. Either get the hexcodes from a [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) or use e.g. `echo -n @ | od -A n -t x1` for the hexcode of "@" (without leading zeros). It retuns 40, so `printf "\x40"` will print an "@".

Comment: later on I found this escaping for single quotes:
`awk '{ printf "'\''%s'\''\n", $0 }'`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have GNU sed or BSD sed, then you had missed the `-i` (or `-i ''` with BSD sed) option for `sed` editing in-place.

You don't need to use both `sed` and `perl` to make it done, single invocation from one of them can do it all:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i 's/.*/"&",/' file
```

or some fun with another standard tool:

```
:|paste -d'"",' - file - -
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\r/"\1",/g' filename
```

It will remove the carriage return and add the quotes and comma.

Output:

```
"aav",
"afv",
"adad",
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so nice, but pretty robust way (since you can separately control beginning and end of line) is following:

```
sed -i s/^/\"/ file.txt && sed -i s/$/\",/ file.txt
```

Of course this can be done with paste tool as well.

ALTERNATIVE:

Using SED references:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)/\"\1\",/' file.txt
```

NOT: Sed solution applies only if you are using GNU sed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/.*/"&",/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close